# Stack Overflow is addictive, like some esoteric learning game!

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Stack Overflow a type of game?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/is-stack-overflow-a-type-of-game)

OK, this is not a real question, but I still want to know whether it'd be wrong for me to feel the way I do about Stack Overflow:

Of late, I've become addicted to Stack Overflow - I spend hours on-end hunting down other people's questions so I can give an answer, I chase after documentation to learn stuff I can't asnwer or stuff I learn from other's answers. Sometimes I am late to give the best answer, but I've come to love this way of learning things!

So when I am not doing my day-job-code-n-hacks, I chill with a cup of cold water, trance music and Stack Overflow - it's become so addictive, apart from [Hacker News](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_News) and [Popular Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_Science).

Do others share my feelings? Is it constructive behavior?

Comment: In the end, the only person who can answer this question is yourself. If it's good for you, go ahead - if your answers are good, the community here won't mind

Comment: It can be quite addictive; I'm a recovering addict - I came back to SO after a few years away (I hadn't been relevant to me during my absence). What I've found is that after a few days addiction, the novelty wore off because there are _a lot_ of repeated questions because too many posters don't search.

Comment: So enthusiastic, so rebuffed, so meta.

Comment: You lost me at trance music.