# Is reputation strategy good or bad?

Tags: discussion, reputation, flags

Most of the beginners in SO answer repeated simple questions just for getting reputation rather than to flag these. Of course they are trying to gain reputation but they're also ruining the site by making lots and lots of redundancies. So in this sense is any strategical change needed?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. Such users will always be on the site. If something should be closed, close it. If it ends up being deleted soon after, the rep for those who answered goes as well. Which in turn makes their efforts pointless. So instead of trying to change them, perhaps focus on the validity of the question asked.

Comment: @SobinAugustine - I dont think your question is a mistake, but I do consider these answers as noise that the Internet generates :))

Comment: Looks similar to [the game of SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/is-stack-overflow-a-type-of-game) question.

Comment: This general concept has been brought up quite a number of times.  Do you have some specific suggestion as to what to do about it?  Note that not everyone doing this is just doing it for the rep.  For some questions it's just easier to spend 10 seconds typing a 2 sentence answer than to spend a minute to finding a duplicate, and verifying that it truly is an exact dup, and not just related.

Comment: Says who? You're painting with an awfully broad brush there, @Sobin.

Comment: @Bart maybe if useful flagging gets any reputation, can improve the situation or is it something like this already?

Comment: @SobinAugustine It's been proposed before, in various forms, but never implemented.

Comment: @Servy maybe with these repeated ones, its easy to fill up the first page of a search engine result about a topic with the Q&A finds here

Comment: Related, I think: [The bike shed problem and SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31253), [Are duplicates creating broken windows?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52530)

Comment: `ruining` is pretty strong...

Comment: Relevant: [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5)

Comment: I'm downvoting this because of a couple of statements: "Most of the people" (most means "the majority", and you've not provided any evidence that more than half of the people who answer here are doing so for the reason you state), and "ruining the site" with no evidence that it's being "ruined" by anything, much less the unsubstantiated behavior you claim exists. Wild exaggeration and unsubstantiated claims without any evidence to support them do not make a good question, even at Meta. I personally answer questions to help people, and vote to close when the question is unclear or a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers)

Comment: @KenWhite friend,by "Most of the people" i exactly mean "the majority", in the context of repeated questions, just go to these sites and have look, the questions which are common will get lots of answers before get flagged, and i am not here to make great questions, just thought about it and make it a discussion topic in meta discussion,(here it says in the about 'This site is for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites') so just set a topic,and it was my first question and may be it not the way to do this here.

Comment: @Sobin: I'm quite familiar with SO (as you can see by my profile if you check). I've been spending significant time here the past three years or so. The "majority" of answers are posted by people who have answered more than one question, many of which are quite complex. Your "majority" is just nonsense (nothing personal - wild, meaningless statements based on nothing are always nonsense). If you want us to accept "majority", show actual facts where you can prove that more than 50% is true. When you have facts, back them up and you'll have a question. This is noise.

Comment: @KenWhite ok, the majority came maybe because of my perspective,like, even most my friends in SO and some guys with low reputations in SO are trying to answer rather than to flag repeated ones, next thing is,  don't accept the 'majority thing',why aren't you telling about the relevancy of the rest of the parts, always cursing about the mistake i made in the question.

Comment: @Sobin: I'm not "cursing" about anything. I'm ignoring the rest of what you wrote because it's nonsense based on the exaggerated and meaningless claims you based it on. If it's not "the majority", and it's not "ruining the site", then there's no issue. You have no evidence to support your claims ("Well, I know three people counting me that post at SO, and two of them do it" does not make a "majority of SO posters"), and therefore there's no actual problem. It's just meaningless typing. :-) Your edit changes nothing - "Most of the beginners" without numbers showing > 50% of them is still noise.

Answer (score 1):

I answer simple questions because I like to help beginning programmers.  I also do it because I don't program as much as I used to, and it helps me from getting too rusty.

My 10k+ reputation and 99 cents will buy me a cup of mediocre coffee.

Comment: While I do disagree with the OP's presentation of the concept, closing a question as a duplicate is generally just as helpful, if not more helpful, to the OP as answering, and is more helpful for everyone else.