# Include footnote notation in Markdown engine

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown footnotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes)

The wonderful [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) version of Markdown allows using footnotes via the `[^1]` or `[^jama]` notation. Footnotes can then be inserted at the end of the document. They can also be handled inline using `^[this notation]`. Footnotes are then displayed quite elegantly at the bottom of the document.

Understandably, this may not be very useful for Stack Overflow, but many of the other Stack Exchange sites like skeptics, biology, math, etc. do quite a bit of referencing, citing, and linking. I think this addition to the Stack Exchange Markdown engine would be very useful. Has this already been decided or can it be accomplished?