# Content of footnote to be displayed in tooltip

Tags: feature-request, tooltips

I won't exactly hold my breath for this one, since there are probably more important features to be added, but...

Would it be possible to display the contents of a footnote (or, say, the first 50 characters) in the tooltip?

One of the reasons for requesting this - imagine a [good](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143), and fairly long answer, that cites a lot of resources. It would be quite tedious to keep scrolling down and then back up.

Comment: Similar, perhaps duplicate: [Markdown footnotes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes)

Comment: @hichris123 not really a dupe as far as I can see, this one explicitly asks for the footnote to appear in the tooltip.

Comment: @hichris123 It is indeed similar, but, if I understand it correctly, the linked request was about markdown. This request asks for something to be displayed in the tooltip.

Comment: I think we first have to agree on what a footnote is, what the markdown for that should look like. In the answer you linked I wouldn't be able to parse out the *footnotes* and show them in a tooltip.

Comment: @rene Hm, I could've sworn that there _was_ a standard way (without resorting to ordered lists and the like) to insert footnotes. Since it's not there, I guess there's no clean and neat way of doing what I've requested. :|

Comment: In the [HTML specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#footnotes) it says: *HTML does not have a dedicated mechanism for marking up footnotes. Here are the suggested alternatives.*. In the [Common Mark spec (v0.26)](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.26/) the word *footnote* is only used to illustrate the differences between all markdown implementation: *Some extended the original Markdown syntax with conventions for footnotes, tables, and other document elements.*. As SE might migrate to Common Mark footnotes first need to be a thing there i guess.